# Finding a Formula for a Repeating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find a mathmatical formula to represent these two series but am totally baffled how I am supposed to figure it out.  I am not just looking for the formula... How would I actually go about finding this?

$X:10,2,14,7,9,12,31$

$Y:10,10,2,2,14,14,7,7,9,9,12,12,31$

So I need something that will take $X_i$ and turn it into $Y_i$ for $i = 0,1,2,3,4...$

The other one is:

$X:5,3,7$

$Y:5,3,7,5,3,7,5,3,7,5,3,7,5,3,7...$

Without using the **mod** function

Comment: So do you require the single formula/algorithm to yield both outputs given the inputs (awfully like a coding challenge)

Answer (score 1):

The $1$st sequence is $Y_i=X_{\lfloor{i/2}\rfloor}$

The $2$nd sequence is $Y_i=X_{i-\lfloor{i/3}\rfloor\cdot3}$

Comment: is there any half way reasonable way to produce the second one without using a mod function?

Comment: @user125621: What's you definition for "half way reasonable"? IMO, using mod is "full way reasonable".

Comment: just any other way besides using the mod

Comment: @user125621: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the numbering/indexing starts from 1 so we have:
$x_1, x_2, x_3, ... $  and  $y_1, y_2, y_3, ... $

The way I see it for the 1st one you have: $y_i = x_{\lfloor(i+1)/2\rfloor}$
The 2nd one is: $y_i = x_{((i+2)\ mod\ 3)+1}$

Comment: Am I missing something? How could that work?   i = 0, Y = X(1/2);   i = 1, Y = X1;   i = 2, Y = X(3/2);   i = 3, Y = x2;   And so on

Comment: Just like that. Put some i values in there and you'll see.

Comment: I agree the second one is really easy when using a mod function... I was trying to avoid using that

Comment: It's not so easy if we assume the numbering starts from 1. I just corrected the formula for the 2nd one. I don't see how you can avoid using mod, you'll end up (re)defining the mod function yourself which is essentially the same.